# tengo un problema con la maquina de aws porque no implementa todo el codigo php

Tags: php, aws

hola estoy usando una maquina de aws, ya le instale el apache2 y el php, para comprobar que funciona cree un archivo php con phpinfo() dentro y funciona pero cuando subi mi formulario a la pagina sale la pantalla en blanco y al darle a inspeccionar la etiqueta body esta vacia siendo que en la maquina esta el codigo completo

foto del body vacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo del formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario Upcycling</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
        <?php include("con_db.php");?>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/42-426834_wallpaper-green-solid-color-single-one-colour-plain.jpg); background-size: 100vw 100vh;">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="background-color:lightgreen; border-radius: 10px; border: solid 2px green;">
            <h1 style="color:lightyellow">Formulario</h1>
            <input type="text" name="nombreContacto" placeholder="Nombre de Contacto">
            <input type="text" name="cargoEmpresa" placeholder="Cargo de la Empresa">
            <input type="text" name="nombreEmpresa" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa">
            <input type="text" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion">
            <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <?php
                $clus = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT productos FROM producto");?>

                <select name="producto" class="select">
                    <option value="">Seleccione un producto</option>

                <?php $types = array();
                while(($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($clus))) {
                    $types[] = $row['type'];
                }

                $j=0;

                for($i=1; $i<=count($types); $i++){
                    $var = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT productos FROM producto WHERE num=$i");
                    $var1=mysqli_fetch_array($var);

                    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$var1[0]."</option>";
                    
                    $j = $j + 1;
                    }echo '</select>';
                ?>
            <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">
            <input type="text" name="comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios">
            <input style="color:lightyellow" type="file" name="imagen" placeholder="adjunte una foto si desea">
            <input type="submit" name="registrar">
        </form>
            <?php
            if(@$_FILES['imagen']['name'] == ""){
                include("correo.php");
                include("correoCliente.php");
            }
            else{
                include("correo1.php");
                include("correoCliente.php");
            }
            include("registrar.php");
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

¿¿saben cual podria ser el problema??

Comment: Soy un viejales que no ve nada en esa imagen del código. Por favor, todo el código se comparte siempre como texto. Y de paso, revisa los logs de PHP, a ver qué sale.

Comment: Por favor pegar el código correspondiente y lee el siguiente enlace: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dónde define conex?  Hay errores en error.log?

Comment: no sabia que error.log mostraba errores, estoy recien aprendiendo todos esto, muchas gracias